# How can I use node postgres query synchronized

Tags: javascript, postgresql

How I can query amount of rows from database and pass them in while loop?

```
client.connect();
async function rows() {
await client.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE proceeded = false", 
   function (err, result) {
    return result.rows.length;
   });
}

while (parseInt(rows(),10) > 0) { 
  do some work
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, seems you use a "pg" library so you can't do synchronous query because "pg" is a non-blocking client. But probably you don't need it. In your code you use async-await syntax and it is a good asynchronous way of using this library, but you don't need callback to process query results.
Perhaps your code might look like this:

```
async function rows () {
  const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE proceeded = false')
  let i = 0
  while (i < 10) {
    console.log(res.rows[i])
    i++
  }
  await client.end()
}
rows()
```

Or better this way:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const Cursor = require('pg-cursor')
const pool = new Pool()
const client = await pool.connect()
const query = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE proceeded = false'
const cursor = client.query(new Cursor(query))

cursor.read(10, function (err, rows) => {
  if (err) throw err
  rows.forEach((row, i, arr) => console.log(row))
  cursor.close(() => {
    client.release()
  })
})
```

NOTE: I didn't run it, so it is just a sample.
More examples you can find at https://node-postgres.com/